# Why does this code call CloseHandle on a NULL handle?

Tags: python, c, winapi

I'm trying to recreate some functionality found on the psutil project (https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) using ctypes. Using psutil would be an overkill for what I want, which is simply check if a given pid is currently running or not.

The code snippet I'm trying to recreate is the [pid_is_running function](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Dnjw9wRLlM4/trunk/psutil/arch/mswindows/process_info.c&q=pid_is_running%20package%3apsutil%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=150).

```
int
pid_is_running(DWORD pid)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    DWORD exitCode;

    // Special case for PID 0 System Idle Process
    if (pid == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                           FALSE, pid);
    if (NULL == hProcess) {
        // invalid parameter is no such process
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            return 0;
        }

        // access denied obviously means there's a process to deny access to...
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            return 1;
        }

        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        PyErr_SetFromWindowsErr(0);
        return -1;
    }

    if (GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &exitCode)) {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return (exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE);
    }

    // access denied means there's a process there so we'll assume it's running
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    PyErr_SetFromWindowsErr(0);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return -1;
}
```

I don't understand why the code is closing a NULL handle. Is that truly necessary? Is it wrong or could potentially cause an error?

I would also appreciate any input on what I could come up with so far

```
import os
import shlex
import subprocess
import ctypes as c
import ctypes.wintypes as w

PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION   = 0x0400L
PROCESS_VM_READ             = 0x0010L             
ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER     = 0x57L
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED         = 0x5L
STILL_ACTIVE                = 0x103L
FALSE                       = 0L

def start(cmd):
    l = shlex.split(cmd)
    return subprocess.Popen(l).pid

def get_pid(hProcess):
    pid = w.DWORD()
    return c.windll.kernel32.GetProcessId(hProcess);

def pid_is_running(pid):
    # adapted from psutil library 
    # http://code.google.com/searchframe#Dnjw9wRLlM4/trunk/psutil/arch/mswindows/process_info.c&q=pid_is_running%20package:psutil\.googlecode\.com&l=150

    pid         = w.DWORD(pid)
    hProcess    = w.HANDLE()

    if pid.value == 0L:
        return True

    if pid.value < 0L:
        return False

    flags = PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ
    hProcess = c.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(flags, FALSE, pid)
    try:
        if 0 == hProcess:
            # invalid parameter is no such process
            last_error = c.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
            if last_error == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                return False

            # access denied obviously means there's a process to deny access to...
            if last_error == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
                return True
            #return -1 #  Error? Should I throw an exception
            raise Exception('Could not find process and an error occurred')
        else:
            exitCode = w.DWORD()    
            if c.windll.kernel32.GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, c.byref(exitCode)):
                return exitCode.value == STILL_ACTIVE

            # access denied means there's a process there so we'll assume it's running
            if c.windll.kernel32.GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
                return True
            #return -1 #  Error? Should I throw an exception
            raise Exception('Process found and an error occurred')
    finally:
        if hProcess != 0:
            c.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess)
```

Comment: Using already-written and already-debugged code is not overkill, it's not wasting time reinventing the wheel (and introducing new bugs to your codebase — less you write, the better).

Comment: Post your code here, not off-site.

Comment: I would also feel inclined to agree with you, but I don´t want to have an over 10,000 lines code base as a dependency when what I need is less than 50

Answer (score 1):

It was probably automatically generated to close it every return path. Not even C programmers were stupid enough to free resources on every path, they use a goto-based cleanup idiom instead.

Of course,

> compile against ntdll functions not exposted in the API

probably indicates that the code uses internal NT API functions, which are bound to change and break your code for lolsies at any time in the future.

Comment: +1 for lolsies. I'm trying to get some code working on Windows 8 and I can only imagine what sort of hacks and liberties have been taken with the API up to now (I know in many places it does X when the documentation says don't do X). So don't do it. Follow the public API and its documentation.